# TabPy Server configuration error when running flow from command line

Tags: tableau-api, tabpy

I have a tableau prep flow which uses python script. When i run the flow from tableau prep, it works.
However, i am using command line alongside task scheduler to automate the flow. When running the automated flow; i am encountering the error below:
[image]

I have already configured the connection to tabpy in the tableau prep itself. Previously this used to work. But i am now getting this error. Should the TabPy configuration be added to the json file used for credentials? if so, in what format should it be?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. Just had to include the following command in the json file:
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking/answering a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)